# zsh agnoster theme chagne prompt/ps1

Tags: zsh, prompt, ps1

How can I change the prompt of my zsh shell while still retaining the cool coloring that agnoster provides? For people who don't know, it looks like this
[image]
I want to add some things like ! and \u before the working directories. I've tried the usual PS1="! \u \w" but it just gives this:
[image]

EDIT: I found the right escaped characters for inserting information, but it cancels out the styling
[image]
How can I change the prompt while maintaining the styling?

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to customise the theme, i.e. `.oh-my-zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme`, add your own function to the build_prompt function and add whatever you need to the prompt:

```
## Main prompt
build_prompt() {
  RETVAL=$?
  prompt_status
  prompt_virtualenv
  prompt_context
  prompt_dir
  prompt_git
  prompt_hg
  prompt_end
}
```

I personally added a `prompt_custom` stub, which I then replace with the real prompt function in my `.zshrc`, so I only have to maintain that small customisation (probabaly worthty of a pull request at some stage...)

```
prompt_custom() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the prompt_context() in .oh-my-zsh/themes/.zsh-theme with the following block of code

```
prompt_context() {
     if [[ "$USER" != "$DEFAULT_USER" || -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then
         prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)~"
     fi
}
```